# Looping and linking with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

How would you build a grid using a nested foreach, defining one node for each iteration?

If I were coding in Python, I would write:

```
nodes = {}
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(5):
         node = nodes[(i, j)] = create_node(location=(i, j), text="node text")
         if (i-1, j) in nodes:
             add_path(nodes[(i-1, j)], node, style=hstyle)
         if (i, j-1) in nodes:
             add_path(nodes[(i, j-1)], node, style=vstyle)
```

My code needs to be more complicated than this (it's not a simple grid), but doing this would be a great start.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by linking? It would be better to know exactly what you want to accomplish, and what you have attempted so far as a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: By linking, I mean the `add_path` calls, which I am using as a Python equivalent of tikz's `path`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the Python code does (does `add_path(<node>)` link the current node to the one specified in the argument?), but I gave it a shot anyway.

Here's my interpretation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={draw,text width=0.5cm},
    x=1.1cm,
    y=1.1cm]
\foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
    \foreach \j [
        evaluate=\j as \jprev using int(\j-1),
        evaluate=\i as \iprev using int(\i-1)] in {1,...,5} {
        \node (\i-\j) at (\i,-\j) {\i\,\j};
        \ifnum \jprev = \i
            \draw [red, very thick] (\i-\jprev) -- (\i-\j);
        \fi
        \ifnum \iprev = \j
            \draw [red, very thick] (\iprev-\j) -- (\i-\j);
        \fi
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I think this might work!  I'm going to see if I can adapt this to my more complicated case and post a comment if I have any problems.  Are these `(\i-\j)` node names?  Can I say `(xnode-\i-\j)`?

Comment: @NeilG: Yes, yes and simply use `({1 + 2 * \i}, {2 + 3 * \j})` for the `at` part in `\node`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting this weird error:  `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `e' or `ev' (in 'int(1-1) evaluate')`  (Also, thanks Caramdir for explaining how to apply transformations to nodes.  My research turned up the dollar sign notation, which is uglier, I think.  I'll use yours.)

Comment: My fault.  I think I got this working.  Thanks a lot!!